# How to get line number in file opened in Python

Tags: python

I'm searching for a list of terms in a file. I want to print the line number in the file where the term was found.

This is the code I'm using to find the term:

```
w = "wordlist.txt"
d = "demofile.txt"

keys = [key for key in (line.strip().lower() for line in open(w)) if key]

with open(d) as f:
    print("File", w)
    for line in f:
        for key in keys:
            if key in line.lower():
                print(key)
```

Comment: Use `enumerate`: `for lineno, line in enumerate(f):`. Keep in mind that this starts numbering from 0.

Comment: @9769953  - you can use start parameter to start from where you want

Comment: @DonKnacki Thanks! All these years using `enumerate`, to never know about the `start` parameter (because I never had to look up the documentation for `enumerate`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you could use `enumerate`, which returns a tuple of an iterator count, and the value for the current iteration in your iterable variable (the filehandle `f` in this case).

`file_to_be_read.txt`:

```
Hello, this is line 0
And this is the second line
```

`your_readscript.py`:

```python
with open('file_to_be_read.txt', 'r'):

    for line_no, line in enumerate(f):
        print(f'{line_no}: {line}')
```

Where `line_no` now represents the current line number within the body of the for loop, starting at 0.

Output:

```
0: This is line 0
1: And this is the second line
```

If you want it to start at 1 (or any other integer), you can pass that as argument to the `start` parameter of `enumerate` like so:

```python
for line_no, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
    ...
```